# Korean unit words for text chunks

Tags: vocabulary

What are Korean unit words for counting various sizes of text chunks? For example, `section`, `paragraph`, and etc. are the English ones.

Answer (score 4):

In descending order in size, they are:

#### General uses

- **권 (卷)**<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: **a unit** of amount of books.
- 부 (部)<sup>[Dictionary definition #2]</sup>: **a unit** of amount of books and newspapers.
- 편 (篇)<sup>[Dictionary definition #2]</sup>: **a unit** of amount of pieces, such as books, poetry, and movies.
- 편 (篇)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: **a unit** of amount of books forming part of a work or series; i.e. volumes.
- 호 (號)<sup>[Dictionary definition #3]</sup>: **a unit** of .......
- 편 (篇)<sup>[Dictionary definition #3]</sup>: **a unit** of .......
- **장 (章)**<sup>[Dictionary definition #1 and #2]</sup> or 가름<sup>[Synonym]</sup>: chapter.
- **절 (節)**<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: paragraph.
- **단어 (單語)** or **낱말**: word.
- **마디** or 소절 (小節)
- **글자 (글字)** or **자 (字)**: letter; or, **a unit** of number of letters.

#### In linguistics

- 절 (節)<sup>[Dictionary definition #8]</sup> or 마디<sup>[Dictionary definition #7]</sup>: clause.
- 구 (句)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: phrase.

#### In poetry

- 구 (句)<sup>[Dictionary definition #2]</sup>.

#### Legal

- 편 (篇): part.
- 장 (章): chapter.
- 절 (節): section.
- 관 (款)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: subsection.
- 조 (條)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: article.
- 항 (項)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>: *paragraph*.
- 호 (號): subparagraph.
- 목 (目): item.

#### In budget compilation

- 장 (章)<sup>[Dictionary definition #3]</sup>.
- 관 (款)<sup>[Dictionary definition #2]</sup>.
- 항 (項)<sup>[Dictionary definition #2]</sup>.
- 목 (目)<sup>[Dictionary definition #1]</sup>.
- 절 (節)<sup>[Dictionary definition #4]</sup>.

The reason why they're mostly one-letter words is maybe because they're almost unit words.

---

## Definitions

#### (Usually used as a unit; noun) 권 (卷)

> - 1. 책을 세는 단위.
> - 2. 여럿이 모여 한 벌을 이룬 책에서 그 순서를 나타내는 말.
> - 4. 주로 고서(古書)에서 책을 내용에 따라 구분하는 단위.

#### (Usually used as a unit; noun) 부 (部)

> - 2. 신문이나 책을 세는 단위.

#### (Usually used as a unit; noun) 편 (篇)

> - 1. 형식이나 내용, 성질 따위가 다른 글을 구별하여 나타내는 말.
> - 2. 책이나 영화, 시 따위를 세는 단위.
> - 3. 책의 내용을 일정한 단락으로 크게 나눈 한 부분을 나타내는 말.

#### (Usually used as a unit; noun) 호 (號) [호ː]

> - 3. 신문이나 잡지 따위의 정기 간행물이 간행된 차례나 그 성격을 나타내는 말.

#### (noun) 장 (章)

> - 1. 글의 내용을 체계적으로 나누는 구분의 하나. [Synonym] 가름<sup>2</sup>.
> - 2. (수량을 나타내는 말 뒤에 쓰여) 글의 내용을 구분한 것을 세는 단위.
> - 3. 예산ㆍ결산에서의 구분의 하나. 장 아래에 관, 항, 목 따위가 있다.

#### (noun) 관 (款) [관ː]

> - 1. 법률문 따위의 조항.
> - 2. 예산 편성의 한 과목. ‘항<sup>8</sup>’(項)의 위이다.

#### (noun) 항 (項) [항ː]

> - 1. 내용을 체계적으로 나누어 서술하는 단위의 하나. 법률이나 문장 따위의 각개의 항목을 구분할 때 쓴다.
> - 2. 예산 편성에서 나누는 분류의 하나. 관(款)의 아래이며, 목(目)의 위다.

#### (noun) 절 (節)

> - 1. 글의 내용을 여러 단락으로 서술할 때의 한 단락.
> - 4. <경제> 예산 편성에서 나누는 분류의 하나. 목(目)의 아래이다. 현재는 잘 쓰지 않는 항목이다.
> - 8. <언어> 주어와 술어를 갖추었으나 독립하여 쓰이지 못하고 다른 문장의 한 성분으로 쓰이는 단위. [Synonym] 마디<sup>1</sup>.

#### (noun) 마디

> - 4. 말, 글, 노래 따위의 한 도막. [Synonym] 소절<sup>1</sup>(小節).
> - 7. <언어> [Synonym] 절<sup>8</sup>

#### (noun) 조 (條)

> - 1. ‘조목<sup>1</sup>’이나 ‘조항<sup>2</sup>’의 뜻을 나타내는 말.

#### (noun) 목 (目)

> - 1. <경제> 예산 편성에서 나누는 분류의 하나. 항의 아래이고 절의 위이다.

#### (noun) 구 (句)

> - 1. <언어> 둘 이상의 단어가 모여 절이나 문장의 일부분을 이루는 토막. 종류에 따라 명사구, 동사구, 형용사구, 관형사구, 부사구 따위로 구분한다.
> - 2. 시조나 사설(辭說)의 짧은 토막.

---

## References

- [*Standard Korean Language Dictionary* (*표준 국어 대사전*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Korean_Language_Dictionary)
- https://elaw.klri.re.kr/kor_service/lawsystem.do
- [http://zetawiki.com/wiki/편,_장,_절,_관,_조,_항,_호,_목](http://zetawiki.com/wiki/%ED%8E%B8,_%EC%9E%A5,_%EC%A0%88,_%EA%B4%80,_%EC%A1%B0,_%ED%95%AD,_%ED%98%B8,_%EB%AA%A9)

Comment: What parts of speech are these? Are they all nouns?

Comment: @topomorto Yes, they are nouns.

Comment: This answer should be elaborated by someone else..